# Проблема с определением контекста this

Tags: javascript, ооп

```js
var f = function() {
    this.x = 5;
    (function() {
        this.x = 3; 
    })();
    console.log(this.x); 
};

var obj = {x: 4, 
    m: function() {
        console.log(this.x); 
    }
};

obj.m.call(f) //--> undefined
```

Почему в данном случае вернется undefined, а не 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в call ты в качестве аргумента передаешь объект, который и будет this в вызываемой функции. А здесь ты передаешь функцию. Функция - это тоже объект, но у нее нет свойства x, поэтому возвращается undefiened.

Я не совсем понимаю, что ты хочешь сделать, но чтобы получить 5, передавая функцию, ты можешь сделать так.

1. Самой функции назначить свойство x (функции - это тоже объекты,
   так что так можно сделать).

   ```
   var f = function() {};
   f.x = 5;
   ```
2. Вернуть из функции объект со свойством x и передать в call не
   функцию, а вызов функции.

   ```
   var f = function() {
     return { x: 5};
   };
   //Твой код
   obj.m.call(f())
   ```